# Assign progressive count of values in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, count

I have a data frame like this:

```
IP_address
   IP1
   IP1
   IP1
   IP4
   IP4
   IP4
   IP4
   IP4
   IP7
   IP7
   IP7
```

I would like to take count of unique values in this column and note the progressive count as a field by itself. At the end, it should look like this:

```
IP_address  IP_address_Count
   IP1               1
   IP1               2
   IP1               3
   IP4               1
   IP4               2
   IP4               3
   IP4               4
   IP4               5
   IP7               1
   IP7               2
   IP7               3
```

There is also the possibility that the IP_addresses would not be grouped. It could appear as:

```
IP_address
    IP1
    IP1
    IP4
    IP4
    IP1
    IP4
    IP7
    IP4
    IP7
    IP4
    IP7
```

In that case, I would want:

```
IP_address  IP_address_Count
   IP1               1
   IP1               2
   IP4               1
   IP4               2
   IP1               3
   IP4               3
   IP7               1
   IP4               4
   IP7               2
   IP4               5
   IP7               3
```

[How to assign count of unique values to the records in a data frame in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331210/how-to-assign-count-of-unique-values-to-the-records-in-a-data-frame-in-python/57282989#57282989)

I originally started with the above code but then wanted to develop on and have been unsuccessful as of yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply group by the relevant field and then do a cumulative count (gave desired result on my end):

```
df['IP_address_count'] = df.groupby('IP_address').cumcount()+1
```